# Update a DataFrame with duplicate destination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to update a dataframe with another one but with multiple "destination". Here is an example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'], 'category':['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], 'value1':[None, 1, None, None], 'value2':[None, 10, None, None]})

  name category  value1  value2
0    A        X     NaN     NaN
1    B        X     1.0    10.0
2    C        Y     NaN     NaN
3    A        Y     NaN     NaN


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A', 'C'], 'value1':[2, 3], 'value2':[11, 12]})

  name  value1  value2
0    A       2      11
1    C       3      12
```

And the desired result would be

```
  name category  value1  value2
0    A        X     2.0    11.0
1    B        X     1.0    10.0
2    C        Y     3.0    12.0
3    A        Y     2.0    11.0
```

I don't think pd.update works since there are two time 'A' in my first DataFrame.

pd.merge creates other columns and I think there is probably a more elegant way than to merge these columns manually after their creation

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fillna` after mapping the column `A` in `df1` with the corresponding values from `df2`:

```
mapping = df2.set_index('name')['value']
df1['value'] = df1['value'].fillna(df1['name'].map(mapping))
```

If you want to `map` multiple columns:

```
mapping = df2.set_index('name')
for col in mapping:
    df1[col] = df1[col].fillna(df1['name'].map(mapping[col]))
```

Alternatively you can try `merge`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='left', suffixes=['', '_r'])
df.groupby(df.columns.str.rstrip('_r'), axis=1, sort=False).first()
```

---

```
  name category  value1  value2
0    A        X     2.0    11.0
1    B        X     1.0    10.0
2    C        Y     3.0    12.0
3    A        Y     2.0    11.0
```

Comment: Well, It does answer my question but I haven't been precise enough at the beginning^^ What if have several value (value1, value2) columns? in my case I have five of them

Comment: @Irpie Can you update the question with required information?

Comment: Just did. I could do five times your initial answer but maybe there is a better way

Comment: I did not manage to make the merge version works on my real code. the first() just seems to take the first column and not the first not None value. But the first version is perfect for my use. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Irpie `.first` ignores the `None` values and takes the first `non-nan` value..So i guess `merge` should also work fine..Let me know if it doesn't work!